ggplot2: getting errorbars on the correct columns instead of in between two columns
I have a dataframe of summary stats like this:
cgstats<-structure(list(vars = 1:6, n = c(54, 52, 50, 44, 52, 40), mean = c(4.74074074074074, 
4, 3.94, 3.59090909090909, 4.21153846153846, 3.525), sd = c(0.483118220040696, 
1.18817705157201, 1.05772184916644, 1.52983023557612, 1.05415217232299, 
1.33948899556165), median = c(5, 4, 4, 4, 5, 3), trimmed = c(4.81818181818182, 
4.14285714285714, 4.075, 3.72222222222222, 4.40476190476191, 
3.65625), mad = c(0, 1.4826, 1.4826, 1.4826, 0, 1.4826), min = c(3, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1), max = c(5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5), range = c(2, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4), skew = c(-1.54991149953069, -0.894226999750809, -0.796407969488971, 
-0.606075887802024, -1.20593774232714, -0.364061783282586), kurtosis = c(1.41233408838418, 
-0.568509615384615, -0.211603066331908, -1.23457219170111, 0.517038755050349, 
-1.04506985944107), se = c(0.0657440624745195, 0.164770510914327, 
0.149584458430953, 0.230630585652136, 0.146184604209703, 0.2117918063353
), low = c(4.61188237829068, 3.67704979860792, 3.64681446147533, 
3.1388731430309, 3.92501663728744, 3.10988805958281), high = c(4.8695991031908, 
4.32295020139208, 4.23318553852467, 4.04294503878728, 4.49806028578948, 
3.94011194041719)), row.names = c("cg_useful", "cg_multi", "cg_methods", 
"cg_infra", "cg_collab", "cg_funding"), class = "data.frame")

I would like to make a plot with "vars" on the x-axis and both mean and median as columns, and I'd like to have errorbars based on the "low" and "high" values in the "mean" columns only.
I found this helpful post and based on that,  did this:
cglong<-pivot_longer(cgstats, cols = c(mean, median))
cglong$low[cglong$name == 'median']<-NA
cglong$high[cglong$name == 'median']<-NA

p<-ggplot(cglong, aes(x=vars, y=value, fill=name))+geom_col(position="dodge")
p1<-p+geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=low, ymax=high))

I get what I want but errorbars are place in between the two columns, though I'd like them to be on the mean (red) columns (see plot).

I also tried the following:
p1<-p+geom_errorbar(data=subset(cglong, name=="mean"), aes(ymin=low, ymax=high))

but the errorbars are still in between the two column types, just like in the plot.
Is there any way I could get them to be on the "mean" columns? Thanks in advance!

Try with + geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = low, ymax = high, group = name), position = "dodge"). See e.g. ggplot2 - Bars non-aligned to error bars
